# npm install -g -D not updating dev dependencies in package.json

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

I've tried opening and closing the open `package.json` editor, and restarting **VS Code**, and running and re-running the `npm install` command at least 8 times but to no avail.

For some reason, the command below does not update my **dev dependencies** in my `package.json` file.

```
$ npm install -g -D webpack
```

I know I can manually add the dependency but just saying and this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are passing the option `-g` which makes npm install the package globally so you can execute the binary directly, remove that flag to install the package locally.

Comment: That hardly should matter. I *want* to install the package globally. I am not sure how that has anything to do with what I am asking.

Comment: If you install the package globally then why would npm care about that specific package.json

Comment: Ah I see! The docs should mention that then that the `--save-dev` only works for local installs. Thanks much, And sorry about being a prick. 6 minutes to go.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try: `$ npm install --save-dev webpack`

This is the recommended way to install webpack from [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack)

Comment: Thank you. I think the npm documentation should mention that global installs with the `-D` flag won't update the package.